# Firestore flutter complex query

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to perform a search in my flutter app and the query I am using is like this:

```
searchUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('User')
            .where("name", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: mySearchController.text)
            .where("name", isLessThan: limit);
```

Now, this gives me the result, but it shows all the docs and now I want to perform 1 more 'where' like this:

```
.where("friends", arrayContains: globals.patientPhoneNum)
```

So my final query looks like:

```
searchUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('User')
            .where("friends", arrayContains: globals.patientPhoneNum)
            .where("name", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: mySearchController.text)
            .where("name", isLessThan: limit);
```

But now, this gives me error:

```
(22.1.2) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(User where friends array_contains # com.google.firestore.v1.Value@ff357562
W/Firestore(16941): integer_value: 0
W/Firestore(16941): string_value: "+919869787899" and name >= # com.google.firestore.v1.Value@9deca
W/Firestore(16941): integer_value: 0
W/Firestore(16941): string_value: "Ra" and name < # com.google.firestore.v1.Value@9deff
W/Firestore(16941): integer_value: 0
W/Firestore(16941): string_value: "Rb" order by name, __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/acm2021-1d053/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Ckpwcm9qZWN0cy9hY20yMDIxLTFkMDUzL2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy9Vc2VyL2luZGV4ZXMvXxABGgsKB2ZyaWVuZHMYARoICgRuYW1lEAEaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAQ, cause=null}
```

**Firestore:**

[image]

Comment: The error message literally couldn't be more informative. You have to create an index. You can create it there: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/acm2021-1d053/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Ckpwcm9qZWN0cy9hY20yMDIxLTFkMDUzL2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy9Vc2VyL2luZGV4ZXMvXxABGgsKB2ZyaWVuZHMYARoICgRuYW1lEAEaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to follow the instructions given by Firebase

1. Open the link that appears on the command line[(this)](https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/acm2021-1d053/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Ckpwcm9qZWN0cy9hY20yMDIxLTFkMDUzL2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy9Vc2VyL2luZGV4ZXMvXxABGgsKB2ZyaWVuZHMYARoICgRuYW1lEAEaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAQ,%20cause=null%7D)
2. Click on Create Index button(blue button on the most bottom right)
3. Wait until the status of the indexing request changes from `Building` to `Enabled` (this step might take 4-5 minutes)
4. The query should work fine now

Comment: Thank you :) I am new and had no idea about it appreciate it